# how to get the current image background id

Tags: android, image

how to get the current image background id

my code is

```
int d = iv.getId();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),d);

// convert bitmap to byte
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();

//Log.e("insert",a);
db1.addFavorite(imageInByte);
e1.setText("");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `iv`? It needs to be the id of an image resource

Comment: what is your requirement? for your kind info u can get id for only view not for its background but u can get the background image view.getBackground() it returns drawable not id

Comment: We need a bit more content: What is `iv` (I assume an ImageView?) and what `db1`? Why do you need the image as byte stream and how do you esure, that the drawable is a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `iv` is an ImageView and that the source image of this ImageView is a Bitmap (which means that the drawable is most likely a *.png in your resources)

Further I assume that you want to get the bitmap, that is currently the image of the `iv` ImageView. Not the background as you have mentioned in your question.

To get the Bitmap and work with, replace your first two lines with this code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```